# Typescript reference own types method in return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to construct several typed models which can be handled in a similar manner prior to sending to storage.  However, I can't figure out a way to determine each models' `model::serialize()` return type.

Base interfaces/model class:

```js
interface ModelSerialized {}

interface ModelInterface {
  serialize(): ModelSerialized;
}

abstract class Model implements ModelInterface {
  serialize(): ModelSerialized {
    return {};
  }
}
```

An example User model:

```js
interface UserSerialized {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

class User extends Model {
  public firstName: string;
  public lastName: string;

  public constructor(props: UserSerialized) {
    super();

    this.firstName = props.firstName;
    this.lastName = props.lastName;
  }

  get name(): string {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }

  serialize(): UserSerialized {
    return {
      ...super.serialize(),
      ...{
        firstName: this.firstName,
        lastName: this.lastName,
      },
    };
  }
}
```

This would live in a separate storage class and handle all models relatively uniformly

```js
interface AuditAttributes {
  updatedAt: string;
}

function serializedAuditModel(
  model: ModelInterface
): ModelSerialized & AuditAttributes {
  return {
    ...model.serialize(),
    ...{
      updatedAt: new Date().toISOString(),
    },
  };
}
```

A test (w/ expected output in comments)

```js
const userAudit = serializedAuditModel(
  new User({ firstName: "Foo", lastName: "Bar" })
);

console.log("User", {
  firstName: userAudit.firstName, // Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'ModelSerialized & AuditAttributes'.
  lastName: userAudit.lastName, // Property 'lastName' does not exist on type 'ModelSerialized & AuditAttributes'.
  updatedAt: userAudit.updatedAt,
})
```

[I also created a link to a sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsAmEA2BlaYOHYALwk2QG8BfAKDtElkRQ2xwElxp4lq6yZAGdCxMhAAUASgBcaLLgJQiJcpgDcdenTgAjYWCiIwyBDjjDhCjsmABbAA44I9iOGvtc3ZnxRVBETE1KTkbJWCJSgChISgIMABXKBBqGi0heh0mXlZkAFVRKGVVKIEhGGAoQwA5ODd5QxUQAHMM5Ata%20ohGo1A27QZzS2tC6GQIAA9IEExPRRxy5EdEvRIEZErqsDqGkT7W9pW14A3One7e5oHA4-WzdBAmxIQwdChJRyh0R2F5MeKkXU0iWQmEiUc0BkWkCQjAAAtgMIAHRbLpuZAAXmW31%20qKq6Ig7ThiJR512KGxXx%20ZMsFzc7R0QhaCWQIG6Miu-VByHiSRSyAABgASKgIpH47YUmjIUXi2mEmiCxkMMFA0L-IolcTqHl85KpGKxITI03gyFQZFFUrkGQAGlhsVNyKNxoqBPpPWQ8slhIdbti5Mu3tJyKDbn9bpokcyKuyPBY-AAgolMMAwEmwH09IlINYjRDMHBIJhM1zDoM6DBEiBXsBHkEVDqKCm02AvDhJIF7At5B2fLkkHQwh3tSFKAAyZCt9OZ7O5iD5wL6gWu5DOnscK3q%202O51roSF4stsDyEAQADuyAAIseZMi3pw8AB5PAHFq743RwLpSsIR6GMgiRFFibKXgURSSFQmwehS8gAEQAGLoOg8F2h0dJwcg8EAEJwFA8HIDQ0gwnQ-5PKYwHQDOpjYtazalqm6YdpIVFQCRyAAPSccgAAq8IoAA5GinqCcgcCzMggnhhAYn4SgNYANYgOgF4gEMAHoC4YboB%208EAmhSwiVhbE0b6nrodxyAAAq4tAYAAJ5ScZ3RiZg6CLmy6CmFMSKmA2jmQlJo7qpO05MRmWYqDmeaCcigQyfIpkRWGmHdJZPG2T89lOdJaVuG5HnWCpPmTH5yABQ5QWCSFTbjsgU40XO0ULsIcWBEeJZlkBRRmZ1J4OsRdBAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be inclined to make `serializedAuditModel()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in the type `S` corresponding to the output of the model's `serialize()` method.  Like this:

```
function serializedAuditModel<S>(
  model: { serialize(): S }
): S & AuditAttributes {
  return {
    ...model.serialize(),
    ...{
      updatedAt: new Date().toISOString(),
    },
  };
}
```

Then when you call it on a `user`, you get a more specific type:

```
const userAudit = serializedAuditModel(user); 
// const userAudit: UserSerialized & AuditAttributes
```

which should be known to have the properties you care about:

```
console.log("User", {
  firstName: userAudit.firstName, // okay
  lastName: userAudit.lastName, // okay
  updatedAt: userAudit.updatedAt, // okay
})
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsAmEA2BlaYOHYALwk2QG9kBfAKHtElkRQ2xwElxp4lq9ZMgDOhYmQgAKAJQAuNFlwEoREuUwBueg3pwARiLBREYZAhxwRIxZ2TAAtgAccEBxHA2OuHi34oqIVFxdWl5W2UQyUpA4WEoCDAAVygQalptYQZdZj42ZABVMSgVNWjBYRhgKCMAOTh3BSNVEABzTORLOoaIJuNQdp1GCysbIuhkCAAPSBBMLyUcCuQnJP0SBGQqmrB6xtF+to7V9eBNrt2evpbBoJON83QQZqSEMHQoKScodCcRBXGJSiGhky2EIiSTmgsm0QWEYAAFsARAA6bbddzIAC8Kx+fzR1QxEA68KRqIuexQOO+v3JVku7g6umErUSyBAPVk1wGYOQCWSqWQAAMACRURHIgk7Sm0ZBiiV0om0IVMxjg4FhAHFUoSDS8-kpNKxOLCFFmiFQqAo4plciyAA0cLiZpRxpNlUJDN6yAVUqJjvdcQpVx9ZJRwfcAfdtCjWVVOV4rAEAEEkphgGBk2B+vokpAbMbIZg4JBMFnuUchvQYEkQG9gE9gqpdRRU+mwN4cAAePAAPikQQciwUNBtLa5yDwdHo4SnADJkG2M1mc3mIAWggbBW7kC6h5xrRqHU6XTvhEWS62wAoQBAAO7IAAil9kKPeXDwAHk8IdWg7kE6MZBBkVYIE8RjIEkxTYuy96FMUUg0OiXoKAARAAYug6CofanT0pSaEAEJwFAqF0DIsL0GBzxmFB0BLmYOJjqEZZphmnZSHRUAUfQAD0vGPDRkHFAxWrQDqLHIAuDErqoub5sM4HoK44boH+qGAjhyzIQRwn0WxYB+l6uH8cg6AANZwAAnkEEbelxDHhvhPQmQJFnWUEF6luWelQI5XlXq5ZmWTZtAyPQQA)

Comment: Thanks @jcalz that's exactly what I was looking for.  I wasn't aware of generics prior to you pointing it out!